# Reuters RIC chain for Eurodollar midcurve options

Tags: options, exchange

Can someone please tell me what this is?

Thanks.

Edit:

The RIC for the straight eurodollar options is 0#GE+, I need RICs for the 1,2,3,4 mid curve options which the IMM/IOM calls GE0, GE2, GE3, GE4.

Comment: I would suggest contacting your account manager. For example, I can't even find the chain you're talking about

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not really quant finance, but more for Reuters hot line...

Answer (score 0):

Here is a definition and explanation.

http://www.sirca.org.au/2011/01/what-is-a-ric-chain/

Comment: I've read all this, but it doesn't answer the question.